# How can I only show my custom credential time in the Login Screen on windows?

Tags: windows

I made my custom credential provider but I'm stuck with the default Microsoft login tiles, like "arshi", which I want to remove(the second tile is my custom provider). I tried tweaking the registry using gpedit.msc, but it didn't work. Can you suggest another approach? Here's a screenshot to give you a clearer idea of what I'm talking about.

[image]